# Problem running a C# Console App with CLR wrapped C++ code

Tags: javascript, c#, c++, clr, sfml

I followed this tutorial: [How to create a CLR Wrapper of C++ for using in C#](https://hintdesk.com/2015/02/06/c-how-to-create-a-clr-wrapper-of-c-for-using-in-c/)
My project builds without a problem and I use the same exact code as the tutorial.

I am trying to run the final C# Console Application. *(double-clicking the built c#.exe file)*
Instead of expected console output "***4.1***", it shows an error:

[image: Error upon running built .exe file]

*Does anyone know why does it say?:*
**Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Clrcs, Version=1.0.7354.20945, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
An attempt was made to load a program with incorrect format. 
File name: 'ClrCs, Version=1.0.7354.20945, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
at Cs.Program.Main(String[] args)**

All the 3 sub-projects in my solution:
- are set to target ***.NET Core***.
- were built as ***Debug*** for ***x86***.
- have required references.

*Why am I trying to achieve this / is there a better solution for my problem?:*
I want to use my ***SFML|OpenGL|C++*** "engine" to draw 3D objects using data from a software running on JavaScript.
I discovered that this software can be connected to a ***C# .dll*** in it's ***.js*** file, so I am trying to wrap my unmanaged "engine" into  **C#** as ***.dll***.

I already know it is possible to open a render window from a dll.
I tried it in a C++ console application, where I imported my "engine" as a .dll.
Next I just need to import the CLR Wrapper to a C# app as a .dll, which the mentioned tutorial explains, 
but there are problems running the .exe file. And I can not figure out why.

In short:
**[SFML|OpenGL]*C++ as .dll*** *>into>* ***C++/CLR Wrapper as .dll*** *>into>* ***C# as .exe***

Could you please help me? In any way?

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly for asking you this question and not making sure this option was saved.

I found a solution:
In the C# project properties -> Build -> Platform target -> changed **from** AnyCPU **to** x86.

[image: C# project properties]